# Align to center

Tags: horizontal-alignment, amsmath, align

I want to align some equations to the equal signs, so I wrote this:

```
\begin{align}
            -3z &=-9\\ 
              z &= 3\\
        -3y-3*3 &= 3\\ 
              y &=-4\\
  2x+8*(-4)+4*3 &= 2\\ 
              x &=11
\end{align}
```

However, because one equation is much longer than the others, all the equations appear somewhat at the right of the page:

[image]

How can I make the equal signs appear in the middle while still aligning all the equations to them?

Answer (score 14):

A simple approach would be to duplicate the contents of the *widest* entry (either left or right) on the opposite side, accommodating for some overlap:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\begin{document}
\lipsum[2]
\begin{align*}
            -3z &= -9 \\
              z &=  3 \\
        -3y-3*3 &=  3 \\
              y &= -4 \\
  2x+8*(-4)+4*3 &=  2 \\
              x &= 11
\end{align*}
\lipsum[2]
\begin{align*}
            -3z &= -9 \\
              z &=  3 \\
        -3y-3*3 &=  3 \\
              y &= -4 \\
  2x+8*(-4)+4*3 &=  \rlap{2}\phantom{2x+8*(-4)+4*3} \\
              x &= 11
\end{align*}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

---

Alternatively, if you're not concerned about numbering the equations, then you can use the following construction:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\usepackage{array}% http://ctan.org/pkg/array
\newsavebox{\mymathbox}
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\begin{lrbox}{\mymathbox}$}r<{$\end{lrbox}\llap{\usebox{\mymathbox}}}}%
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\begin{lrbox}{\mymathbox}$}l<{$\end{lrbox}\rlap{\usebox{\mymathbox}}}}%
\begin{document}
\lipsum[2]
\begin{align*}
            -3z &= -9 \\
              z &=  3 \\
        -3y-3*3 &=  3 \\
              y &= -4 \\
  2x+8*(-4)+4*3 &=  2 \\
              x &= 11
\end{align*}
\lipsum[2]
\[
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
  \begin{array}{R@{{}={}}L}
            -3z & -9 \\
              z &  3 \\
        -3y-3*3 &  3 \\
              y & -4 \\
  2x+8*(-4)+4*3 &  2 \\
              x & 11
\end{array} \]
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

This constructs an `align*` in the form of an `array` and places the contents on either side of the equal sign in a zero-width box. Consequently, then equations seem centred based on `=`.

Note that `\rlap` and `\llap` uses `\makebox`, which inserts its contents in text mode. Hence the switch back to math mode via `$` in the automated construction of the `L` and `R` column types.

Comment: This doesn't use `\displaystyle`. When using `\displaystyle` though, no spacing is added to "tall" entries

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem, but I also wanted to place my final (longer) equation **in a box.** For boxes in align I used **\Aboxed** from mathtools. Using the concept from the solution by @Werner above, I found a solution for a **center, aligned around '=', boxed equation**, which is to place on each side of the equation the text of the other side as **\phantom** text. That way, the equation can become symmetrical, without using \rlap which messes with the box.

I know this is not exactly what the original post asked for, but I think it would be a very useful addition, since there aren't many posts available discussing the center aligned concept.

Also, I have included, as an extra, a simple way to **increase \Aboxed padding**, which I could not find anywhere online. The idea is to use one 0-widht-rule for y padding, and two 0-height-rules for x padding. The offset should be placed at minus half the font size, in my case that is 12pt/2=-6pt.

As for the y padding, 20pt occured because I want 4pt above, and for pt below. That gives me 4pt+4pt+12pt = 20pt, where 12pt is the font size.

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\usepackage{mathtools}                          % for Aboxed, to box in alignat environment

\begin{document}
\lipsum[2]
\begin{align*}
            -3z &= -9 \\
              z &=  3 \\
        -3y-3*3 &=  3 \\
              y &= -4 \\
  2x+8*(-4)+4*3 &=  2 \\
              x &= 11
\end{align*}
\lipsum[2]

\begin{align}
            -3z &= -9\nonumber \\
              z &=  3\nonumber \\
        -3y-3*3 &=  3\nonumber \\
              y &= -4\nonumber \\
\phantom{2\implies} \Aboxed{\rule[-6pt]{4pt}{0pt}2x+8*(-4)+4*3 &=\rule[-6pt]{0pt}{20pt}2\rule[-6pt]{4pt}{0pt}}\phantom{2x+8*(-4)+4*3 \implies}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

And here is the result I wanted to achieve:

[image]