# Center equals sign in presence of proof justification and tags

Tags: spacing, formatting, align, text

When I use the standard `align` environment with a single `&`, the result is intuitive; the equals sign is on centered on the page.

```
\begin{align}
     gw_4g&=w_1 \notag \\
     hw_4h&=w_3 \tag{e} \\
     ghg&=k \tag{f}
\end{align}
```

[image]
Now, if I want to add some text justification to the right of the equation, I would add some spacing and my text.

```
\begin{align}
     gw_4g&=w_1 \qquad \qquad \text{from equation (a)} \notag \\
     hw_4h&=w_3 \tag{e} \\
     ghg&=k \tag{f}
\end{align}
```

[image]
The problem is, the equals sign is no longer aligned with the center of the page. I want the equals to be in the center of the page, no matter what. The justification text should appear to the right of the equation, and then the label all the way to the right, like this.
[image]

I've searched around and attempted to use multiple columns with `\align` and `\alignat`. [This](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69748/align-to-center) is the closest answer that has come to solving my problem, but unfortunately I don't know LaTex well enough to understand how to apply whatever is going on in the `\array` environment to my scenario.

Thanks so much! Opinions on whether or not this is the "best practice" way to format equations are very welcome, too.

If possible, it would be ideal if the text was aligned as well. When the spacing is consistent, the text doesn't stay aligned because the width of the content on the right side of equation is variable.
[image]

Ideally, it would look something like this:
[image]

With my limited LaTeX knowledge, I would describe this as "like, 2 columns, but they're both shifted right one columns-length so that the equals sign is in the middle".

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  To make the width of the descriptive text "invisible", enclose it all in `\mathrlap{\qquad ...}`.  Requires the `mathtools` package.

Comment: Thanks so much! That's really handy. Is there any way to then vertically align all the text on the right of the equation, while still keeping the equals sign in the middle of the page?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "all the text".  Do you mean something like a paragraph at the right?  If that's it, then you might try a minipage (after the `\quad`).  You'll have to give it a width, of course, and an option `[t]` will cause the top line to be baseline-aligned with the line of math.  And use `\raggedright`, either the default, or the equivalent from the `ragged2e` package, depending on whether hyphenation is needed.

Comment: Thanks, Barbara! I'll try that out. I updated the question to be more specific as to what I meant by "all the text".